# InputStream is not working properly

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

I am a beginner in android. I am trying to work on Sockets. But my `InputStream` is not reading the data as expected. It is getting out of the method after `j = inputStream.read(arrayOfByte, 0, i);`  Please help me.

```
public void readinputstreamforid(final String ip, final int port){
    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try {
                socket=new Socket(ip,port);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[10000];

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (socket.isConnected()) {
                int j = 0;
                int i = arrayOfByte.length;
                try {
                    j = inputStream.read(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
                    if (j == -1)
                        throw new IOException("not working");
                    if (j == 0)
                        continue;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final String strData = new String(arrayOfByte, 0, j).replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "");
                Log.d("hello","recieved: "+strData);

            }
            try {
                IOUtils.write("!#@\n",socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: If an error happens, you are logging it, but then you continue with the code, where more errors can then happen. When an error happens, STOP and exit from the function. Also, you are trying to write to the socket's `OutputStream` AFTER the socket has disconnected. What are you really trying to accomplish with this code? What kind of data are you trying to process? It looks like you are trying to read lines of text. Wrap the `InputStream` inside a `BufferedReader`, then you can use its `readLine()` method in your loop.

Comment: `InputStream.read()` returns -1 when the end of the stream is reached. For a socket, that means when the connection is closed. That is not an error condition, so don't throw an exception. Just break the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But when checking with breakpoints, its neither getting in to `if (j == -1)` nor giving any error. And also I followed your suggestion of not throwing exception, but it didn't worked. And through debugging it is showing that the socket is not closed when reading it. Please help me from this. @RemyLebeau

Comment: "*its neither getting in to if (j == -1) nor giving any error*" - that is physically impossible. Either `read()` throws an exception (which you are catching but then discarding), or it returns a value that the `if` then evaluates.

Comment: `j == 0` means you have a bug: you supplied a zero length to `read()`. `continue` is a strange way to handle that. Your try-catching is poor. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

If an error happens, you are logging it, but then you continue with the code, where more errors can then happen.  When an error happens, *STOP* looping and exit the function.  `InputStream.read()` returns -1 when the end of the stream is reached.  For a socket, that means when the connection is closed.  That is not really an error condition, so you don't need to throw an exception. Just break the loop.  You can wrap the `InputStream` inside of a `BufferedReader` so you can use its `readLine()` method instead of reading bytes manually.

Also, you are trying to write to the socket's `OutputStream` *after* the socket has already disconnected.  That will never work.

Try something more like this:

```
public void readinputstreamforid(final String ip, final int port){
    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                OutputDataStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                do {
                    String data = in.readLine();
                    if (data == null)
                        break;

                    Log.d("hello", data);
                    IOUtils.write("!#@\n", out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                }
                while (true);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its not working....  It is getting out of the method after `String data = in.readLine();`, but app is running without crashing. Data is in `ASCII` charset so i changed `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with `"ASCII"`. Will be there any problem with that ?

Comment: UTF-8 is 100% compatible with ASCII, but you can use `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII` if you want. As for the failure, you need to more specific. What does "getting out of the method" actually mean? A method either flows to the end and exits implicitly, returns explicitly, or throws an exception. What is actually happening in your case? And you never explained what the socket data actually looks like that is being sent to you. Is it actually linebreak-delimited, or is it something else? You have provided almost no details about your situation.

Comment: The expected data after sending `!#@\n` is  `*.%$n!D7a*e#`. I am developing an app for controlling my `Arduino`. It is linebreak-delimited. This method is calling by a fragment, and it is written inside a service. I am new to android, so please help me.

Comment: @krishna and what is the *actual* problem? "Getting out of the method" is not descriptive. Does the Arduino expect you to send something first and it replies? Because your code is the other way around, it is expecting the Arduino to send something first and then you reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now....I thought if i start reading inputstream continously, then i can get data by sending outputstream at any time to get reply. And i am using the same way for reading data at click events. And its working there. Can u explain me why it was wrong.